# Angular 2+ > Conditional Observable Mapping

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, observable

I try to do a conditional mapping of several Observables. First I want to do a request to see if I need to get IP. If true, I get Ip before send Post Request.

Here is my 2 Observables:

```
// NEED IP
this.init$ = this.http.get(API_URL + '/init').pipe(
    tap((response: any) => {
      this.init_need_ip = response.need_ip
    })
);

// IP WAN
this.ip_wan$ = this.http.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json").pipe(
    tap((response: any) => { this.ip_wan = response.ip })
);
```

And my fonction:

```
getIp(model, url, params, options = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.init$.pipe(
    concatMap(() => {
      if (this.init_need_ip) {
        this.ip_wan$;
      }
    }),
    concatMap(() => {
      return this.http.post<{model}>(url, JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, params, {ip_wan: this.ip_wan, ip_lan: JSON.stringify(this.ip_lan)})), options);
    }),
);
```

}

But I got an error:

> Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type
> '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput'.   Type 'void'
> is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.

If I try to return something in my else like:

```
return this.init$.pipe(
    concatMap(() => {
      if (this.init_need_ip) {
        this.ip_wan$;
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
    }),
    concatMap(() => {
      return this.http.post<{model}>(url, JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, params, {ip_wan: this.ip_wan, ip_lan: JSON.stringify(this.ip_lan)})), options);
    }),
);
```

I got another error from my service where the function is called:

> TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You
> can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: You forgot `return`: `if (this.init_need_ip) {return this.ip_wan$;} ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend passing data through the pipe, instead of assigning it to the component's properties, if they are not needed elsewhere.

If I understand your code correctly, I think you should be able to do something like this:

```js
const init$ = this.http.get('/init');
const ip$ = this.http.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");

init$.pipe(
  switchMap(response => {
    if(response.need_ip){
      return ip$;
    }else{
      return of({})
    }
  }),
  switchMap(response => {
    return this.http.post<{model}>(
      url, 
      JSON.stringify({
        ...params, 
        ip_wan: response.ip_wan,
        ip_lan: JSON.stringify(this.ip_lan),
      }),
      options
    );
  })
)
```

Ideally tho, you should have a service with this API calls, and use it as follows:

```js
this.ipService.init().pipe(
  switchMap(response => response.need_ip ? this.ipService.getIp() : of({})),
  switchMap(response => this.ipService.register(response.ip_wan, this.ip_lan))
)
```

Comment: In fact, I need "need_ip" and "ip_wan" in the template so I need to assign them in the component. But thanks, it works well !

Comment: @MatDepInfo that is great :) if this works as you said, do you mind marking this as a correct answer? Thank you

Comment: It works well but now i got another problem, when I log, the navigation is very very slow. And I get this warning in the console: Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'. Any idea ?

Comment: hmm not really? What kind of navigation? in the code, there is no navigation at all